# Proof that Morse complex is a complex using coherent orientation

Tags: differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

I'm reading the book *Morse Homology* by M. Schwarz, which aims to develop Morse homology in strict analogy with Floer homology. For orientation matters, the book follows the paper

> A. Floer and H. Hofer, Coherent orientations for periodic orbit problems in symplectic geometry. Math. Z. 212 (1993), 13-38.

I'm afraid I can't explain the definition of coherent orientations (which occupy an entire chapter in the book). This question is specific to the book (and/or that paper, since the book uses the same notation from that paper, albeit in a different setting).

I got completely confused when the author proves that the Morse complex is indeed a chain complex. The key lemma is the following:

[image]

Here $f$ is a Morse function, $\mu$ denotes Morse index; broken trajectories are equivalent if they are the boundary points of the same connected component of the unparametrized moduli space of trajectories $\widehat{\mathcal{M}}_{x,y}^f$; $\tau_\sigma$ denotes the characterisitic sign obtained by comparing a given coherent orientation and the canonical orientation given by the tangent field of the flow line.

Here is the proof given in the book.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I understand that the goal is to verify $(4.6)$, but I don't know why this is related to the diagram below. How do we compute the glued orientation $[\hat{u}_{it}]\#[\hat{v}_{it}]$? The definition of such glued orientations is via abstract determinant bundles of the Fredholm operators associated to the trajectories, and I don't see how it's related to the image of $\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}$ in $\widehat{\mathcal{M}}_{x,y}^f$... Could someone explain what this proof is doing? I've spent hours thinking and still cannot make sense of this argument...

Thanks for any help!